# Adaptation of Stern Zero-Knowledge protocol from coding to lattices

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, lattice-crypto

I'm currently working on Zero-Knowledge-proofs in lattice context, for which there exist two major frameworks. One of those two is the adaptation of Stern protocol from code-based-crypto.

There is in particular $2$ articles :

- [KTX08]  https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2008/53500376/53500376.pdf
- [LNSW13] https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/569.pdf

which build the lattice version of Stern protocol.

In coding theory: Stern allows to prove knowledge of a vector $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^{n}$ such that $Hx = y\bmod\ 2$. With $H \in \mathbb{F}_2^{m \times n},\ y \in \mathbb{F}_2^{m}$ public.

In [KTX08] : They managed to prove knowledge of a binary vector $x$ such that $Ax = y\bmod\ q$, but there is no mention on any trial to just apply in a straight manner the protocol with an average ISIS instance : That is to say :
proving knowledge of $x \in \mathbb{Z}_q^m$ such that $Ax=y\bmod\ q$ and $||x|| \le \beta$, $A \in \mathbb{Z}_q^{n \times m}$, $y \in \mathbb{Z}_q^n$ public.
As a permutation doesn't affect the norm, I'm not sure why this should doesn't work.

Does anyone know why?

My guess is that it's related to the lattice-based commitment scheme security: If you find a collision with two binary vectors on those commitments, you break a SIS instance with an optimally small bound, which is not necessarily the case for a collision with higher coefficients vectors. 
Anyway, I wonder if I'm right and/or if there is another reason because I'm not fully convinced.

Comment: please put links to pdfs or full references to the articles you cite